# beaglebone black doesn't autoboot when powered over jack or vdd pins

Tags: beagle-bone, linux

I have a BBB and it works quite well however when I power it over the Barrel connector or over the vdd pins rather then use the usb connection it doesn't automatically boot. When I put the barrel connector and usb in at the same time and then remove the usb it continues running. This is running on ubuntu arm. I have tested that the power supply is between 4.95 and 5.04 V and is capable of sustaining this to just over 1 Ampere

Edit it appear the BBB does boot when supplied with 4.7 V lab power supply at ~0.4A power consumption. So that suggest something is wrong with the power supply. But how do I test it seeing I was able to verify that it can supply 1A at 5V.

This power supply works by feeding a 12V battery into a step down to convert it down to 5V if that matters.
power-supply power linux beaglebone-black beagleboard

Comment: What's the amperage of your non-usb power supply? (Barrel and Vdd)

Comment: max 1A/ 4.95-5.05 V

Comment: I'd recommend trying a 2A power supply.

Comment: But the BBB doesn't normally use more then 0.6A maximum and can be powered over usb (max 0.5A)

Answer (score 3):

Why do so many people keep ["Underestimating the complexity of power supply design"](http://www.smpstech.com/undest.htm)?

I'm sure that you already know that *every* digital electronic device pulls a very brief (transient) surge of power when it is first plugged in and turned on -- at much higher current and power levels than the steady-state current and steady-state power during normal operation.

I'm guessing that your 12V to 5V power supply limits its output current.

Switching-mode power supplies, such as the one on the BeagleBone that converts that 5V to the even lower voltage used by its CPU, often [interact badly (latch up)](http://www.smpstech.com/latch000.htm) with current-limited power supplies during the start-up transient.

Have you looked at the [BeagleBoard FAQ](http://beagleboard.org/support/faq), which says "The power adapter is required to provide 5V ... at least 2A (or 10W) is recommended"?